# Elastic search query help on pagination

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

Unhandled questions KPI should display top 10 records in descending order also need to add one field for timestamp. And for all additional records there should be pagination available. Members should be able to view additional records by navigating through pagination options.

My requirements is for the pagination record should come like 1 to 10 and 11 to 20 and 21 to 30 like wise in this range I  should get the output.

I tried the below query but when I execute the query its not showing up the timestamp field. And it is only giving me the question.keyword. Also If i give the partition range between 11 to 20 it is still showing me the 1st ten records . Whatever range I give I am getting the same output and there is no change in the output

Please correct my below query.

````
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "answer.keyword": "UNHANDLED"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "source.keyword": "On_board"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "MyBuckets": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "question.keyword",
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        },
        "size": "10"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "MyBuckets": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "timestamp",
            "order": {
              "_count": "desc"
            },
            "size": "10",
            "include": {
              "partition": 11,
              "num_partitions": 20
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: you can use from, size parameters

Comment: From is not supported for the Aggregations. It is only working without aggregations. so only used the Partition.

Comment: From is not supported for the Aggregations. **I Am getting the error "reason": "[40:7] [terms] unknown field [from], parser not found"**....It is only working without aggregations. so only used the Partition.Any suggestions

Comment: did you try max_buckets ?

Comment: no i did not tried. Could you please look in to my above query and modify and share it here. I am new to elastic search. Need your help.

Comment: Dear Team, Could you please help me. I am not getting the output properly with the above one query